# ¿Cómo puedo clasificar datos en matrices con numpy?

Tags: python, array, matrices, numpy

quisiera saber si pueden ayudarme a entender un poco más sobre la clasificación de matrices.

El ejercicio se trata de un sistema simple que te pide que ingreses un producto, precio y luego quede registrado, con dos opciones, ordenar y clasificar. Resulta que me he quedado estancado en el clasificar, porque no sé como limitarlos a cada uno de los precios que piden.

Al utilizar un <, > me da el siguiente error TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.str_' and 'int'

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como nota, una matriz suele ser un array que tiene como contenido en cada posicion, otro array ;)

Answer (score 0):

tu error se debe a que tratas de comparar tipos de datos distintos, una comparación únicamente se puede realizar entre mismos tipos da datos.
Ejemplo:

```
>>> dato1 = 1;
>>> dato2 = 2;
>>> print(dato1 < dato2)
False
```

En cambio si queremos comparar un str con un entero ns dará el siguiente error:

```
>>> dato1 = "1";
>>> dato2 = 2;
>>> print(dato1 < dato2)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Teniendo en cuenta esto lo unico que debes de hacer es cambiar tu linea de código en donde aparece:

```
if arr_productos[1] > 100:
    print("Existe")
```

Lo que haremos será convertir arr_productos[1] en un entero y nos quedaría así:

```
if int(arr_productos[1]) > 100:
    print("Existe")
```

Comment: Esa solución no es correcta porque entonces estarás comparando cadenas. Y tendrás falsos resultados como que "2" > "100" (pues efectivamente el "2" va alfabéticamente después del "1" y por tanto del "100". Pero es falso que 2 > 100. Para poder comparar correctamente todo tienen que ser enteros y no strings.

Comment: Correcto, al ingresar el precio de un producto que es 50, de todas formas me muestra por pantalla que existe, siendo que 50 no es mayor que 100

Comment: ¿En este caso que podría hacer? debo separar los datos? de antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Solamente conviertelo a entero: if int(arr_productos[1]) > 100:
    print("Existe")

Comment: Gracias!! ahora si funcionó. Tengo otra duda, ahora está el tema de organizarlos por secciones (precios) debería de crear nuevos arreglos a partir de cada if dependiendo de su condición? soy nuevo programando en python y me enreda un poco el tema de matrices, arrays.

Comment: Como es otro tema en especifico, investiga al respecto y si tienes una problema puntual puedes formular otra pregunta @DanielOrellana